# How to create a desktop shortcut (launcher) for "rdeskop" that is able to receive parameters like remote server Ip address?

Tags: .desktop, rdesktop

I have installed "rdesktop" on my Ubuntu and use it to connect to and manage my Microsoft Windows Servers running Remote Desktop Services. I run it from the linux terminal and pass necessary arguments like screen size or remote server's IP or name and port number. This is an example of what I do:

```
rdesktop  -f my_server_name_or_ip
```

which let me connect to my server in full-screen mode.
Recently I decided to create a desktop launcher (like windows shortcut) on desktop that makes me able instead of every time entering a command in terminal window  just execute the launcher.
In fact I created a file with the following content and after setting suitable permissions and locating an icon picture I could successfully accomplished the job.

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/usr/bin/rdesktop -f servername
Name=rdesktop
Comment=rdesktop
Icon=/home/my_username/Pictures/rdm.png
```

But here is a problem. My launcher works fine just for a specified server name or IP address and my question is how can I create or customize a launcher which be able to receive IP, server name, screen size and other parameters after executing the launcher? something like Microsoft Remote Desktop client.
To add more, I am familiar with GUI clients, like tsclient, Gnome-RDP and KDE Remote Desktop Connection (KRDC), which are graphical front-ends to rdesktop. But I want to know how to pass my favorite parameters on the fly in this special case.